# Popping out a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone View rendered. Now i want when i click on a event, my whole Backbone View pop out and render on a lightbox.

What I am trying to do is:

```
var ViewerModuleAppView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            //On Initialization of View, this.template = template_viewer_module.html.
            template: template,

            events: {
                'click #pop_out': 'popout'
            },
            popout: function(){
                //ViewerModuleAppView gets render on a PopOut Window(may be Lightbox).
            }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a question here. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have many events inside ViewerModuleAppView and i have a another view integrated with it which loads image inside it. What i want is when i click on Popout button, my whole view with events and nested view get rendered outside on another div. But not been able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you're using Backbone.Marionette, so I'm gonna post a marionette answer. Bryan Mann did an excellent series of screencasts on Marionette at BackboneRails.com, but also a screencast that covers the lightbox topic. Watch it here: http://www.backbonerails.com/screencasts/building-dialogs-with-custom-regions

Answer (score 0):

There might be some other events getting triggered along with the popout. Check for e.preventDefault() in popup function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the browser from doing other rendering actions, you could use

```
popout: function() { 
 //do actions( pop up light box)
 return false; 
}
 or
popout: function() {
  //do actions 
  event.preventDefault();
}
```